# Code testing using unittest library in python

Tags: python, unit-testing

For few days I'm trying to lern how to properly use unittest library in Python. I've got some basics but I've made myself a challenge - test two functions that I made before. These are the functions:

```
    def PatternMatch(self, message, number):
        ret_status = 2 # 'No match'
        ret_pattern = -1  

        for pattern in self.PatternList:
            if pattern.active == 1 and pattern.LA == number:
                try:
                    RegExp = re.compile(pattern.regex)
                if RegExp.match(message):
                    ret_status = 1
                    ret_pattern = pattern.ID
                    break

        return ret_status, ret_pattern


    def GetPattern(self, patternID):
        pattern = None
        db = Database()
        query = 'CALL PATTERN_GET'
        query += '(@sql_err_code, @my_status, @my_msg, %s)'
        ret = db.query(query, [patternID])
        if len(ret['data']) == 2:
            pattern = Pattern(ret['data'][1])
        else:
            pattern = Pattern()

        result = {'status': ret['data'][0]}
        return pattern, result
```

How should i start? I have mocked the database connection using the mox library and it works but what about the functionality? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the generality of the question only general advice is possible - basically you need to prepare test data &/or inputs that will perform the following:

1. Code Coverage - force all your execution path down every decision path.
2. Decision coverage - as above but via each way of making a decision - e.g. if a >= 0 needs testing with a < 0, a == 0 and a > 0.
3. Corner case coverage - does the code work with very large, very small, very negative, no  values.
4. Exception coverage: Raise all the exceptions that the documentation says can be raised by the code inside *try* clauses and see if they are handled properly or should be allowed through.
5. Always start each set of test data with a clear statement of what you are trying to achieve in that set of test data.